# enviar un mail con un formulario php

Tags: php, formularios, email

estoy tratando de enviar a un mail los datos de un formulario pero no me los envia
Me muestra hasta el segundo alert. Estoy en enviar.php y no me aparece nada. Me pueden ayudar?

contacto.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Contactenos | Herramientas</title>

    <!-- core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]> --> 
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
</head><!--/head-->

<body class="homepage"> 
<?php require_once('cabecera.php'); ?>   
    <section id="feature">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="center">        
                <h1>Deje su mensaje</h1>
                <h5>Escribanos, le responderemos a la brevedad</h5>
            </div>               
                <div class="row">                       
                    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="post">
                        <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Nombre *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email *</label>
                                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div> 
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Asunto *</label>
                                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Mensaje *</label>
                                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
                            </div>                        
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Enviar Mensaje</button>
                            </div>                      
                        </div> 
                    </form>
                </div>





        </div><!--/.container-->
    </section>

<?php require_once('pie.php'); ?>   

</body>
</html>
```

enviar.php

```
<?php
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];   
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
    $para = 'andoporto@gmail.com';
    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('hola');
    </script>";
    $header = 'From: ' . $email;
    $msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n E-Mail: $email\n Asunto:\n $subject Mensaje:\n $mensaje";
        echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('hola2');
    </script>";  
    /*if ($_POST['submit']) 
    {
                echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('hola3');
    </script>";
        if (mail($para, $subject, $msjCorreo, $header)) 
        {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
            </script>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('fallado');
            </script>";
        }
    } */
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estas enviando tu formulario mediante un `button` `JavaScript`, asi que `if ($_POST['submit'])`  nunca va comprobar si dicha sentencia es verdadero o falso, ya que el identidicador *submit* no existe en tu `PHP`.

Una solución sería cambiar tu *botón* por un `<input type="submit" name="submit" />`

**Ejemplo:**

contacto.php

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="enviar.php" method="POST">
      <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
          <div class="form-group">
             <label>Nombre *</label>
             <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email *</label>
              <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div> 

           <div class="form-group">
               <label>Asunto *</label>
               <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control" required="required">
           </div>

           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Mensaje *</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" required="required" class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>
           </div>                        

           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" />
           </div>                      
      </div> 
</form>
```

enviar.php

```
<?php
   //Reseteamos variables a 0.
   $nombre = $email = $subject = $mensaje = $para = $headers = $msjCorreo = NULL;

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      //Obtenemos valores input formulario
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $email = $_POST['email'];
      $subject = $_POST['subject'];   
      $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
      $para = 'andoporto@gmail.com';

      //Creamos cabecera.
      $headers = 'From' . " " . $email . "\r\n";
      $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8";

      //Componemos cuerpo correo.
      $msjCorreo = "Nombre: " . $nombre;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Email: " . $email;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Asunto: " . $subject;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";
      $msjCorreo .= "Mensaje: " . $mensaje;
      $msjCorreo .= "\r\n";

    if (mail($para, $subject, $msjCorreo, $headers)) {
         echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
         </script>";
    } else {
         echo "<script language='javascript'>
            alert('fallado');
         </script>";
    }
  }
?>
```

Una alternativa si deseas enviar tu formulario mediante tu button y has implementado la ayuda de AJAX podrías actualizar esta línea if (isset($_POST['submit'])) a if (isset($_POST))

**Ejemplo mediante librería PHPMailer:**

Descargar Librería [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

enviar.php

```
<?php
       //Reseteamos variables a 0.
       $nombre = $email = $subject = $mensaje = $para = NULL;

       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

          //Obtenemos valores input formulario
          $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
          $email = $_POST['email'];
          $subject = $_POST['subject'];   
          $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
          $para = 'andoporto@gmail.com';


          //Compones nuestro correo electronico

          //Incluimos libreria PHPmailer (deberas descargarlo).
          require'class.phpmailer.php';

          //Nuevo correo electronico.
          $mail = new PHPMailer;
          //Caracteres.
          $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

          //De dirección correo electrónico y el nombre
          $mail->From = "info@tudominio.com";
          $mail->FromName = "Nombre de dominio";

          //Dirección de envio y nombre.
          $mail->addAddress($para, $nombre);
          //Dirección a la que responderá destinatario.
          $mail->addReplyTo("info@tudominio.com","Tunombre");

          //BCC ->  incluir copia oculta de email enviado.
          $mail->addBCC("copia@tudominio.com");

          //Enviar codigo HTML o texto plano.
          $mail->isHTML(true);

          //Titulo email.
          $mail->Subject = "Nuestro titulo";
          //Cuerpo email con HTML.
          $mail->Body = "
                  <h1>Envio libreria PHPMailer</h1>

                  Nombre: $nombre<br /> 
                  Email: $email <br />
                  Asunto: $subject <br />
                 Mensaje: $mensaje <br />

          "; 

        //Comprobamos el envio.
        if(!$mail->send()) {                   
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
                alert('fallado');
             </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script language='javascript'>
                alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias.');
             </script>";
        } 
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: ahora me aparecen estos mensajes, aunque todavia no llego el mail Notice: Undefined variable: headers in C:\laragon\www\fyfherramientas54\enviar.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined variable: msjCorreo in C:\laragon\www\fyfherramientas54\enviar.php on line 16

Comment: @user1851950 Si lo estas probando desde tu `localhost` no va funcionar el envio de `mail()`, deberas hacer la prueba desde tu servidor. Para solucionar las Notice, simplemente resetea los variable a NULL. Te lo modifico en mi ejemplo.

Comment: estoy usando laragon una suite de desarrollo que me permite enviar mails

Comment: lo subi al servidor pero todavía no se me envía el mail, es normal eso?

Comment: @user1851950 personalmente no lo he utilizado `laragon`. El código del ejemplo lo e implementado en ocasiones y funciona bien, una solución alternativa podrías implementar la librería `PHPMailer`.

Comment: El hecho de que haya aparecido un Notice: Undefined variable: headers, no tiene relacion con el envio del correo o no; independiente si estas en localhost o en un host remoto. Debes definir las variables de la alerta.

Comment: @jolsalazar El  `Notice: Undefined variable:`  no tiene relación con el envió `mail` como has dicho, es por intentar agregar una cadena no declarada. También había puesto en la primera línea `.=` y debe ser `=`

Comment: lo corregi y no manda el mail. Estoy usando hostinger para el alojamiento del sitio.

Comment: @user1851950 Te lanza los alertas de tu `JavaScript` el `PHP`? Te he puesto un ejemplo como alternativa, mediante la librería `PHPMailer`, a ver si tienes más éxito. Un saludo

Comment: @D.Bulten Vi tu comentario sobre enviar desde el localhost. Eso es válido para ualquier función de envío de correo? Es decir no se puede enviar desde localhost ningun correo?

Comment: @JeanGotopo si no tienes instalado en tu *Localhost* un servidor de correo, la función `mail` de `PHP` no te va enviar ningún correo, en cambio sí usas `PHPMailer` si funcionaria. Aquí te dejo una respuesta más completa. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168894/no-envia-correos-por-medio-de-mi-formulario/195312#195312 Un saludo.