# No envia correos por medio de mi formulario

Tags: php, html

Realizo un formulario para enviar un correo con el llenado de mi formulario, pero me marca solo error del `echo` de envio, no se que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Este es mi formulario:

```
</head>

<body>

<form name="formulario_contacto" method="post" action="Enviar_mail.php">
<table width="500px">
<tr>
<td>
<label for="nombre">Nombre: *</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="nombre" maxlength="50" size="25">
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="apellido">Apellido: *</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="apellido" maxlength="50" size="25">
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<label for="email">Dirección de E-mail: *</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="35">
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<label for="tfno">Número de teléfono:</label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="tfno" maxlength="25" size="15">
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td>Asunto:</td>
  <td><label for="asunto"></label>
    <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto"></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>
<label for="comments">Comentarios: *</label>
</td>
<td>
<textarea name="comments" maxlength="500" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</td>
</tr>


</table>
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Este es mi codigo PHP

```
<?php

 $texto_mail=$_POST["comments"];

 $destinatario=$_POST["email"];

 $asunto=$_POST["asunto"];

 $headers="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n ";

 $headers.="Content-type: text\html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

 $headers.= "From: Prueba Juan <micorreo@gmail.com>\r\n";

 $exito=mail($destinatario, $asunto, $texto_mail, $headers);

 if ($exito){

     echo"Mensaje  enviado con exito"; 

 }
    else

 {


     echo"Error de envio";
 }




?>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado un servidor de correo en tu servidor?

Comment: Tengo instalado XAMPP

Comment: XAMPP incluye un servidor web con Apache, y soporte preconfigurado para PHP, MySQL/MariaDB y Perl, no trae un servidor de correo.

Comment: De echo ya configure XAMPP para el envio de correo, no se si mi codigo es el que me esta causando problemas

Comment: Aquí tienes una [pregunta similar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/81211/250) con instrucciones para configurar el correo en PHP.

Comment: Alvaro Montoro ya realice lo que esta en la pregunta y continua sin enviar ningun correo y solo me sale el echo de "Error de envio"

Comment: ¿Estás usando mercury?

Comment: No, no uso mercury

Comment: Lo estás haciendo en local? <br>
Si es así, no se va a enviar nunca el correo. Necesitas de un servidor alojado que muestre el smtp.

Comment: asantana Ya configure Mercury y desde ahi si puedo enviar correos sin problema pero desde mi formulario no lo puedo hacer

Comment: Por si acaso, te recuerdo que el valor que devuelve mail (true/false) significa que se ha aceptado para enviar, pero no que haya llegado al destino. Revisa la documentación php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php

Comment: Mira este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost

Comment: Lo estás probando en local simplemente para desarrollar y hacer pruebas? Subirás el desarrollo a algún hosting una vez esté completado? O lo dejarás en tu misma máquina?

Comment: Pudieras instalar y configurar un servidor local SMTP en tu servidor recomiendo que uses la plataforma de GOOGLE y en la configuración de tu PHPMailer indicar los datos solicitados y desde ese momento ya podrá desde lo que estas diseñando enviar correos desde el formulario o desde donde desees..!

Answer (score 13):

En primer lugar, debes instalar un servidor de correo, para que la función `mail` funcione en `localhost` o tu servidor con soporte `PHP`, ahora si deseas evitar la instalación de un servidor de correo, podrías optar por la famosa librería `PHPMailer`.

La función `mail` de `PHP` devuelve `true` si ha sido aceptado, de lo contrario `false`.

> **Nota:** Es importante tener en cuenta aunque el correo es aceptado para su envío, **NO** quiere decir que el correo haya alcanzado el destino indicado.

### Parámetros a pasar:

`to`,  Destinatario/s del correo.

`subject`, Título del correo electrónico a enviar.

`message`, Mensaje a enviar. Cada línea debería separarse con un CRLF (`\r\n`). Las líneas no deberían ocupar más de 70 caracteres.

**Opcional**

`additional_headers`, Cadena a insertar al final de la cabecera del correo. Se usa normalmente para añadir cabeceras extra (`From`, `Cc` y `Bcc`). Las cabeceras múltiples adicionales deberían separarse con un `CRLF`(`\r\n`).

`additional_parameters`, El parámetro `additional_parameters` puede usarse para indicar opciones adicionales como opciones de línea de comandos al programa que está configurado para usarse cuando se envía correo, definido por la opción de configuración `sendmail_path`.

### Ejemplo práctico:

*Enviar un correo con cabeceras extra.*

```
<?php
$para      = 'destino@destino.com';
$titulo    = 'El título';
$mensaje   = 'Hola mundo :)';
$cabeceras = 'From: tucuenta@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: tucuenta@dominio.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

//Enviamos y comprobamos si ha sido aceptado.
if (mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras)) {
   echo 'El correo fue aceptado';
} else {
   echo 'Hubo un error.';
}
?>
```

> **Nota:**  Si cualquier línea de tu mensaje es más larga de 70 caracteres, se debería usar `wordwrap()`. Un ejemplo: `$mensaje = wordwrap($mensaje, 70, "\r\n");`

[Manual mail()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php)

### PHPMailer

*Veamos una alternativa, sin la necesidad de tener que instalar un servidor de correo.*

Incluimos la librería `PHPMailer` ([descargar desde GitHib](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/releases)):

```
//Importar clases de PHPMailer en el espacio de nombres global.
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Componemos nuestro correo:

```
//Nueva instancia de PHPMailer.
$mail = new PHPMailer;
//Caracteres utf-8.
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';   
//Usar SMTP.
$mail->isSMTP();
//Habilitar la depuración de SMTP:
// 0 = off (Usar en producción)
// 1 = Mensaje cliente
// 2 = Mensaje cliente y servidor
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
//Nombre de host del servidor de correo.
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
// Usar
// $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// Si su red no admite SMTP sobre IPv6
// Establezca el número de puerto SMTP - 587 para TLS autenticado, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission.
$mail->Port = 587;
//Sistema de encriptación para usar - ssl (obsoleto) o tls.
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
//Si se debe usar la autenticación SMTP.
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Tu usuario Gmail.
$mail->Username = "tu_cuenta@gmail.com";
//Contraseña de tu cuenta.
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";
//Desde (from).
$mail->setFrom('tu_cuenta@gmail.com', 'Nombre');
//Dirección de respuesta alternativa.
$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');
//Destino (to).
$mail->addAddress('destino@destino.com', 'Daniel');
//Título del correo electrónico a enviar.
$mail->Subject = 'Soy el titulo';
//Leer un cuerpo de mensaje HTML desde un archivo externo, convertir imágenes referenciadas a incrustadas,
//convertir HTML en un cuerpo alternativo básico de texto plano
$mail->msgHTML("Tu cuerpo HTML");    

//Envíe el mensaje, revise si hay errores.
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Tu mensaje fue enviado.';       
}
```

[Fuente GitHub](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)

> **Nota:** Quiero recordar para que funcione nuestra cuenta `Gmail` con `PHPMailer`, hay que **Activar** el acceso a **aplicaciones menos seguras**.

**Cambiar el acceso a la cuenta para aplicaciones menos seguras**

Para mantener más protegidas tus cuentas de Google del trabajo, del centro educativo o de otro grupo, bloqueamos las aplicaciones menos seguras para que no puedan acceder a ellas. Si tienes una cuenta de este tipo, se te mostrará el error "Contraseña incorrecta" cuando intentes iniciar sesión. Si es así, tienes dos opciones:

- Opción 1: instala una aplicación más segura que utilice medidas de
  seguridad más sólidas. Todos los productos de Google, como Gmail,
  utilizan las medidas de seguridad más recientes.
- Opción 2: cambia la configuración para permitir que las aplicaciones
  menos seguras accedan a tu cuenta. Esta opción no es recomendable
  porque puede facilitar el acceso a tu cuenta a otra persona. Si
  quieres permitirlo de todas formas, sigue estos pasos:
         Ve a la sección [Aplicaciones menos seguras](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) de tu cuenta de Google.
         Activa Permitir el acceso de aplicaciones menos seguras. Si no ves este ajuste, es posible que el administrador haya desactivado
  el acceso de las aplicaciones menos seguras a la cuenta.

Comment: +1 por sugerir usar PHPMailer y sobre todo comentar que es **necesario** tener un servidor de correos instalado en tu servidor para que funcione. El hecho de que hace falta tener un servidor de correo y configurar php.ini es un dolor de cabeza para muchos que creen que con usar mail() pueden enviar emails.

Comment: @Killbunny gracias amig@. Si, a mí personalmente me gusta más usar `PHPMailer`, a ver si tengo tiempo y pongo un ejemplo. Un saludo.

Answer (score 5):

Teniendo en cuenta que la función mail() no tiene un valor de retorno que nos permita una depuración en caso de error, una sugerencia es usar la función  error_get_last() cuando mail() falla (retorna falso). Por ejemplo,

```
$exito = mail('ejemplo@micorreo.com', 'Noticias', $mensaje);
if (!$exito) {
    $mensajeError = error_get_last()['message'];
}
```

[Crédito: stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186725/how-can-i-get-the-error-message-for-the-mail-function/20203870#20203870)

> Importante: Cabe aclarar, según los comentarios a esta respuesta, que ésto podría
>   ser sólo válido para Windows.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$destino= "xxxxxx@hotmail.com";
$contacto="Xeoms";
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"]; 
$contenido = "nombre :". $nombre . "\nCorreo :" . $email . "\nmensaje :" . $mensaje;
mail($destino, "contacto", $contenido);
header("Location:contacto.html");

?>
```

aqui un ejemplo de como enviar correo. Solo funciona en un hosting

Answer (score 4):

Primero que nada tienes que verificar que tu servidor sea capaz de enviar correos mediante la función mail de PHP, cosa que no suele venir configurada por defecto en servidores locales como LAMP, XAMPP, WAMP, MAMP, ...

Otra cosa, algunos hosting como por ejemplo, GoDaddy, tienen muchos problemas al utilizar la función mail de PHP (los correos no suelen llegar o son marcados como SPAM).

Para evitar este tipo de problemas podrías utilizar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), es sencillo de utilizar, orientado a objetos y en el enlace podrás encontrar varios ejemplos muy buenos.

Y en caso de que quieras seguir utilizando mail te recomiendo cambiar tu código en esta sección por lo siguiente:

```
 if ( mail($destinatario, $asunto, $texto_mail, $headers) ) {
     #Envío correcto ...
 } else {
     #Error ...
 }
```

Tu código será más legible y ahorrarás unas cuantas líneas de código.