# Error de correo: debe proporcionar al menos una dirección de correo electrónico del destinatario

Tags: php, phpmailer

tengo un apk en php, la cual envía correos electrónicos.

este es mi código:

```
                $sql = "select EMAIL, iden from planilla";      

                $rpt = mysqli_query($sub_db,$sql)or die(mysqli_error());
                //$asunto = 'Aviso de Deuda'; 

                $mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"
                $body             = "Este es un mensaje automatico...";


                $mail->From       = "no-responder@collins.cl";
                $mail->FromName   = "Francisco Acevedo";



                $mail->Sender = 'facevedo@x.cl';



                $mail->Subject = 'Aviso de deuda en ...';


                $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";
                $mail->MsgHTML($body);

                $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n'; 
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n';

                $mail->IsSMTP();
                $mail->Host = "mail.x.cl";


                // optional
                // used only when SMTP requires authentication  
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'x';
                $mail->Password = 'x';


                while ($des = mysqli_fetch_array($rpt)) {
                    $destinatario = $des['EMAIL'];

                    mail($destinatario,$mail->Subject,$body,$headers);

                }   

                    if(!$mail->Send()) {
                      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                      exit;
                    } else {
                      echo "Message sent!";
                    }
                }  
              }
            }
```

envia los correos de forma exitosa, pero por alguna razon el programa se detiene y me arroja el siguiente error.

```
 You must provide at least one recipient email address. Mailer Error: You must provide at least one recipient email address.
```

intente algunas soluciones, pero persiste el mensaje y el apk se detiene, pero si envia de forma correcta los correos electronicos..

Comment: Has probado cambiar `$mail->Sender` por `$mail->addAddress('facevedo@x.cl', 'Nombre');`, ya que tu mensaje de error te dice que debes *proporcionar al menos una dirección de correo electrónico del destinatario*.

Comment: no, lo probare y te comento

Comment: Perfecto, te dejo un ejemplo práctico de PHPMailer usando la cuenta Gmail quizás te puede interesar, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168894/no-envia-correos-por-medio-de-mi-formulario/195312#195312, un saludo.