# ¿Por que no me llega correo de PHPMailer? (00webhost)

Tags: php, html, phpmailer, hosting

mi problema es que subi mi pagina web, a 00webhost pero el problema esta en el envio de formulario de contacto ya que aunque le doy a enviar me manda en mensaje de que si se envio el correo, pero cuando reviso en la bandeja no aparece nada, y aunque intente con muchos cambios ninguno me funciono. Y este es el codigo mas basico que he utilizado:

```
<?php
$mail_para = "correo@gmail.com";
$subject = "Prueba de envio de mail con PHP";
$message = "erggwgegr";

$mail = mail($mail_para, $subject, $message);

if ($mail) {
 echo "Su mail se a enviado correctamente";
header("Location: ");
} else {
 echo "A ocurrido un error al intentar enviar su mail";
}
?>
```

ó

```
<?php
$mail_para = $_POST['mail'];
$subject = $_POST['asunto'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$mail = mail($mail_para, $subject, $message);

if ($mail) {
 echo "Su mail se a enviado correctamente";
header("Location: ");
} else {
 echo "A ocurrido un error al intentar enviar su mail";
}
?>
```

He leido en muchos blog y me dice que tengo que hacer un correo del dominio o algo asi, y si es asi alguien me explica como se crea? o hay una configuracion que tengo que activar o desactivar de mi correo personal (es una cuenta comun y corriente de gmail) para que me llegue los correos o algo que agrege mas al codigo. o algun otro hosting u otra cosa que tenga que hacer para que me llegue el correo

p.d: este es el codigo de mi formulario que utilizo:

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="POST" id="formulario">
                    <h2>Enviar Mensaje</h2>
                    <div class="InputBox">
                        <input type="text"  name="name" id="name" class="name" placeholder="" required="required">
                        <span>Nombre Completo</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="InputBox">
                        <input type="text" name="mail" id="mail" class="email" placeholder="" required="required">
                        <span>Email</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="InputBox">
                        <textarea name="message" class="asunto" placeholder="" id="" required="required"></textarea>
                        <span>Escribe tu Mensaje</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="InputBox">
                        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Comment: No esta en la bandeja de spam?

Comment: Hola, quizás esta respuesta te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168894/no-envia-correos-por-medio-de-mi-formulario/195312#195312, luego estas usando la función ```mail()``` de PHP, y no PHPMailer que es una librería diferente y que debes incluir en tu proyecto si deseas usarlo, en la respuesta que te he dejado tienes varios ejemplos.

Comment: No, no aparece ni en el spam