# PhpMailer me queda recargando la pagina

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un correo desde mi hosting pero phpmailer deja recangando la pagina hasta que sale un error 500, no sale ningun error ni que funciono correctamente, cuando quito la funcion de php mailer funciona correctamente, y aunque se quede cargando me guarda los datos en la base de datos

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once('PhpMailer/Exception.php');
require_once('PhpMailer/PHPMailer.php');
require_once('PhpMailer/SMTP.php');

require_once('Config/config.php');
require_once('Config/bd.php');


class bonos_model extends Conexion {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->bd = Conexion::conexion();
        $this->nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $this->apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $this->cel = $_POST['numero'];
        $this->correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $this->ocupacion = $_POST['ocupacion'];
        $this->codigo = rand(111111, 999999);
    }

    public function set_bono() {
        $stmt = $this->bd->query("INSERT INTO bonos(nombre, apellido, celular, correo, ocupacion, bono) VALUES ('$this->nombre', '$this->apellido', '$this->cel', '$this->correo', '$this->ocupacion', '$this->codigo')");

        if (!$stmt) {
            die("Error en la consulta comuniquese al soporte y envie este error: (" . $this->bd->errno . ")" . $this->bd->error);
        }else {

            $correo = new PHPMailer(true);
            try {
                $correo->SMTPDebug = 0;
                $correo->isSMTP();
                $correo->Host = 'host';
                $correo->SMTPAuth = true;
                $correo->Username = 'correo';
                $correo->Password = 'contrasena';
                $correo->STMPSecure = 'ssl';
                $correo->Port = 465;

                $correo->setFrom('correo');
                $correo->addAddress('correo destinatario');

                $correo->isHTML(true);
                $correo->Subject = 'Recibe tu bono de 1.000 PESOS en nuestras tiendas';
                $correo->Body = '<h1>Felicidades!!</h1> <br> <p>Por el registro de tus datos has ganado un bono de 10.000 PESOS COLOMBIANOS para comprar de nuestros productos de decoracion.<p> <br> Redimelos con este codigo:<br> <h2>Codigo</h2>';

                $correo->send();
                echo 'mensaje enviado correctamente';

            }catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'no se envio correctamente'. $correo->ErrorInfo;
            }

            return $this->codigo;
        }
    }

}
```

Cambie algunos datos por privacidad como host, contraseña, correos y los nombres de los destinatarios,
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Si pones ```$correo->SMTPDebug = 2;``` te lanza algún error?

Comment: Sige igual carga y carga hasta que me sale que "Reques Timeaout Error 500"

Comment: @Juancalde Te recomiendo que compruebes que puede enviar información / comunicarse con tu base de datos. Normalmente, el código de error 500 esta asociado a problemas con la base de datos.

Comment: Podrías añadir en tus archivos .php que en los que estableces conexión a la base de datos un control de errores donde, si la conexión a la base de datos ha sido correcta te imprima por pantalla ("Conexión establecida") y de lo contrario un error. Así sabrás si el problema reside en la conexión a la base de datos.

Comment: Como dije cuando hago la consulta y queda cargando los datos del formulario se envian a la base de datos y se guardan lo que no se envia es el correo

Comment: @Juancalde Entiendo, otro posible motivo por el cuál puede saltar este error, ya que como dices, no es por lo que te he mencionado, es lo siguiente : Si utilizas una cuenta de correo de gmail para enviar los correo tienes que activar el acceso a aplicaciones no seguras.

Comment: Así a simple vista no veo error en el código del correo, quizás te puede ayudar esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/168894/no-envia-correos-por-medio-de-mi-formulario/195312#195312

Comment: @Juancalde A lo referente a lo que te he comentado de permitir el acceso a aplicaciones no seguras te adjunto [este enlace](https://docs.rocketbot.com/?p=1567) donde se explica como hacerlo.

Comment: Como dije no uso gmail sino un hosting

Answer (score 0):

No se si será esta la causa del fallo, pero prueba a poner:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
```

Es decir, añade el SMTP en los use. Yo lo estoy utilizando ahora mismo y me funciona bien.

Luego busca en internet SMTP "tu_hosting" y te saldrá la información del host, la seguridad y el puerto.

Te dejo aquí los datos que tengo puestos en mi proyecto, en mi caso utilizo gmail.

```
                $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;
                $mail->isSMTP();
                $mail->Host= 'smtp.gmail.com';
                $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
                $mail->Username = 'correo';
                $mail->Password = 'contraseña';
                $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
                $mail->Port = 587;
                
                //CONFIGURACIÓN DE CORREO
                $mail->setFrom('correo', 'nombre');
                $mail->addAddress($correo_usuario);
                $mail->addCC('correo');
                
                $mail->isHTML(true);
                $mail->Subject = 'asunto;
                $mail->Body = "cuerpo";
                $mail->send();
```

En mi caso utilizo el puerto 587, que requiere TLS.

En tu caso, en SMTPSecure prueba a poner PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTSSL;

Comment: ya tengo los datos de mi hosting y del correo con el puerto en este caso no es con gmail sino con hosting

Comment: En ese caso, prueba a poner use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

Comment: Ya lo añadí pero no dejo sige cargando sin ningun avance